# Two conjectures about generalised A329369

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Let $m \geqslant 2$ be a fixed integer.
Let
$$\operatorname{wt}(n,m)=\operatorname{wt}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor,m\right)+n\bmod m, \operatorname{wt}(0,m)=0$$
Then we have an integer sequence given by
$$a(n,m)=(1+\operatorname{wt}(n,m))a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor,m\right), a(0,m)=1$$
and also transform
$$b(n,m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{\operatorname{wt}(n,m)-\operatorname{wt}(k,m)}\operatorname{binmod}(n,k,m)a(k,m)$$
where
$$\operatorname{binmod}(n,k,m)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if $\binom{n}{k}\operatorname{mod} m=0$}\\
1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I conjecture that

- if $m$ is prime, then $b(n,m)$ is always positive (and if $m$ is composite, then there are a lot of negative $b(n,m)$)
- if $m=2(2k+1)$ and smallest $n$ such that $\operatorname{sgn}(b(n,m))=-1$ equals $m$, then $2k+1$ is either prime or a prime power

Is there a way to prove it (or at least one of those conjectures)?

Also here is a pari code for second conjecture:

```
default(parisizemax,10^9)
n=9
wt(n,m)=if(n==0,0,wt(n\m,m)+n%m)
a(n,m)=if(n==0,1,(1+wt(n,m))*a(n\m,m))
b(n,m)=sum(k=0,n,(-1)^(wt(n,m)-wt(k,m))*(if(binomial(n,k)%m==0,0,1))*a(k,m))
c(n,m) = {my(k=0); while (sign(b(k,m)) != -1, k++); k; }
v=vector(2^n,i,if(c(0,2*(2*i+1))==2*(2*i+1),(2*i+1),0))
print(v)
```

It took me an hour and 42 minutes to check values up to 1025, here is a output:

```
[3, 5, 7, 0, 11, 13, 0, 17, 19, 0, 23, 0, 27, 29, 31, 0, 0, 37, 0, 41, 43, 0, 47, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0, 59, 61, 0, 0, 67, 0, 71, 73, 0, 0, 79, 0, 83, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0,0, 97, 0, 101, 103, 0, 107, 109, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 127, 0, 131, 0, 0,137, 139, 0, 0, 0, 0, 149, 151, 0, 0, 157, 0, 0, 163, 0, 167, 0, 0, 173, 0, 0, 179, 181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 191, 193, 0, 197, 199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 211, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 223, 0, 227, 229, 0, 233, 0, 0, 239, 241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 251, 0, 0, 257, 0, 0, 263,0, 0, 269, 271, 0, 0, 277, 0, 281, 283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 293, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 307,0, 311, 313, 0, 317, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 331, 0, 0, 337, 0, 0, 0, 0, 347, 349, 0,353, 0, 0, 359, 0, 0, 0, 367, 0, 0, 373, 0, 0, 379, 0, 383, 0, 0, 389, 0, 0, 0,397, 0, 401, 0, 0, 0, 409, 0, 0, 0, 0, 419, 421, 0, 0, 0, 0, 431, 433, 0, 0, 439, 0, 443, 0, 0, 449, 0, 0, 0, 457, 0, 461, 463, 0, 467, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 479, 0, 0, 0, 487, 0, 491, 0, 0, 0, 499, 0, 503, 0, 0, 509, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 521, 523, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 541, 0, 0, 547, 0, 0, 0, 0, 557, 0, 0, 563, 0, 0, 569, 571,0, 0, 577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 587, 0, 0, 593, 0, 0, 599, 601, 0, 0, 607, 0, 0, 613, 0,617, 619, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 631, 0, 0, 0, 0, 641, 643, 0, 647, 0, 0, 653, 0, 0, 659, 661, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 673, 0, 677, 0, 0, 683, 0, 0, 0, 691, 0, 0, 0, 0, 701, 0,0, 0, 709, 0, 0, 0, 0, 719, 0, 0, 0, 727, 0, 0, 733, 0, 0, 739, 0, 743, 0, 0, 0, 751, 0, 0, 757, 0, 761, 0, 0, 0, 769, 0, 773, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 787, 0, 0, 0, 0, 797, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 809, 811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 821, 823, 0, 827, 829, 0, 0, 0, 0, 839, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 853, 0, 857, 859, 0, 863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 877, 0, 881, 883, 0, 887, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 907, 0, 911, 0, 0, 0, 919, 0, 0, 0, 0, 929, 0, 0, 0, 937, 0, 941, 0, 0, 947, 0, 0, 953, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 967, 0, 971, 0, 0, 977, 0, 0, 983, 0, 0, 0, 991, 0, 0, 997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1009, 0, 1013, 0, 0, 1019, 1021, 0, 0]
```

It contain all odd primes up to 1025 and also 27 and 125. No other composite numbers.

It also took me an hour and 25 minutes to check prime powers up to 4097, here is a output:

```
[-9, -25, 27, -49, -81, -121, 125, -169, -243, -289, -343, -361, -529, -625, -729, -841, -961, -1331, -1369, -1681, -1849, -2187, -2197, -2209, -2401, -2809, -3125, -3481, -3721]
```

Sign is porsitive if prime power in the sequence and negative otherwise. Still 27 and 125, no other composite numbers.

Comment: It seems that if $m$ is a prime then $b(n,m)=1$ iff $n=(m^k-1)/(m-1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.